# Is there a common name for a lower matrix with 1's on diagonal?

Tags: matrices, terminology

This is a very light question. In as few words as possible, I want to describe an $(n \times n)$ matrix $M = \left(M_{i,j} \right)$ which satisfies $M_{i,i} = 1$, $\forall i$, and $M_{i,j} = 0$, $\forall i<j$.

"$M$ is a lower triangular matrix with $1$'s along the diagonal" - is there a more economic way of saying this (i.e. with less words)? Ideally, I hope there exists a common term like "uni-lower triangular" which precisely describes what I want, but I'm not sure if "uni-lower triangular" is right.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is referred to as a **unit** lower triangular matrix. Basically unit means all $1$s on the diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

People often use "unipotent", but this is not quite correct (a unipotent matrix is one that is similar to the kind you describe).